# How to calculate average/std values of minute data of x days using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, moving-average

The purpose of this code is to get average value of the last 3 days of data at every minute of each day.

If today is 2016-01-03 and I want to know the last 3-days of average close value of at 09:30:00 including today, then pseudo formula will be like the below:

3-day average close at 09:30:00 of today = 
(close value at 2016-01-01 09:30:00 + close value at 2016-01-02 09:30:00 + close value at 2016-01-03 09:30:00) / 3

I managed to calculate average/std values of minute data of x days using pandas.
The below code is what I implemented.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# date, time, close
data = [ 
    [20150101, 90100, 100],
    [20150101, 90200, 102],
    [20150101, 90300, 104],
    [20150101, 90400, 106],
    [20150101, 90500, 108],

    [20150102, 90100, 100],
    [20150102, 90200, 104],
    [20150102, 90300, 105],
    [20150102, 90400, 103],
    [20150102, 90500, 102],

    [20150103, 90100, 100],
    [20150103, 90200,  98],
    [20150103, 90300,  99],
    [20150103, 90400, 102],
    [20150103, 90500, 101],

    [20150104, 90100, 100],
    [20150104, 90200, 101],
    [20150104, 90300, 100],
    [20150104, 90400, 100],
    [20150104, 90500, 101],

    [20150105, 90100, 100],
    [20150105, 90200, 102],
    [20150105, 90300, 104],
    [20150105, 90400, 106],
    [20150105, 90500, 108],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'time', 'close'])
df.set_index(['date', 'time'], inplace=True)

################################################################

df.groupby(level=0)
dateidx = sorted(list(set(date for (date, time) in df.index)))
timeidx = sorted(list(set(time for (date, time) in df.index)))
print(dateidx)
print(timeidx)

df['mean'] = np.nan
df['std'] = np.nan

print(df)

idx = len(timeidx)*2
for i in range(5-2):
    slice=df.loc[dateidx[i]:dateidx[i+2]]
    times = slice.groupby(level='time')
    means = times.mean()
    stds = times.std()
    print('[means]')
    print(means)

    for i in range(len(timeidx)):
        df['mean'].iloc[idx] = means['close'].iloc[i]
        df['std'].iloc[idx]  = stds['close'].iloc[i]
        idx = idx + 1

print(df)
```

The below is the final result.

```
                close        mean       std
date     time
20150101 90100    100         NaN       NaN
         90200    102         NaN       NaN
         90300    104         NaN       NaN
         90400    106         NaN       NaN
         90500    108         NaN       NaN
20150102 90100    100         NaN       NaN
         90200    104         NaN       NaN
         90300    105         NaN       NaN
         90400    103         NaN       NaN
         90500    102         NaN       NaN
20150103 90100    100  100.000000  0.000000
         90200     98  101.333333  3.055050
         90300     99  102.666667  3.214550
         90400    102  103.666667  2.081666
         90500    101  103.666667  3.785939
20150104 90100    100  100.000000  0.000000
         90200    101  101.000000  3.000000
         90300    100  101.333333  3.214550
         90400    100  101.666667  1.527525
         90500    101  101.333333  0.577350
20150105 90100    100  100.000000  0.000000
         90200    102  100.333333  2.081666
         90300    104  101.000000  2.645751
         90400    106  102.666667  3.055050
         90500    108  103.333333  4.041452
```

But the problem is, the above code is too slow and somewhat complicated.
So, is there anyone suggests optimal code or solution of this problem ?

ps. I'd like to remove constants those are used in order to calculate position of the rows to be changed. Please suggest more simple and elegant way.

Comment: Can you please describe what you are trying to achieve and your expected result?

Comment: @Alexander Additional comments are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll find this self explanatory.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'time', 'close']).set_index(['date', 'time'])

df['mean'] = df.groupby(level='time')['close'].apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_mean(x, window=3))
df['std'] = df.groupby(level='time')['close'].apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_std(x, window=3))

>>> df
                close        mean       std
date     time                              
20150101 90100    100         NaN       NaN
         90200    102         NaN       NaN
         90300    104         NaN       NaN
         90400    106         NaN       NaN
         90500    108         NaN       NaN
20150102 90100    100         NaN       NaN
         90200    104         NaN       NaN
         90300    105         NaN       NaN
         90400    103         NaN       NaN
         90500    102         NaN       NaN
20150103 90100    100  100.000000  0.000000
         90200     98  101.333333  3.055050
         90300     99  102.666667  3.214550
         90400    102  103.666667  2.081666
         90500    101  103.666667  3.785939
20150104 90100    100  100.000000  0.000000
         90200    101  101.000000  3.000000
         90300    100  101.333333  3.214550
         90400    100  101.666667  1.527525
         90500    101  101.333333  0.577350
20150105 90100    100  100.000000  0.000000
         90200    102  100.333333  2.081666
         90300    104  101.000000  2.645751
         90400    106  102.666667  3.055050
         90500    108  103.333333  4.041452
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. But, my df already has both 'date' and 'time' columns as indexes. And your code assumes 'date' and 'time' columns are normal data columns. Is there another way for df with 'date' and 'time' indexes ?

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you again :)